# Ideas for approaching set theory when you've already studied higher abstractions?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, reference-request, soft-question

I've come to acknowledge (or so I think).

That many of the concepts e.g. in real analysis (like, say, continuity), actually don't (in modern times) boil down just real analysis. But rather, e.g. set theory (which has some more in-depth explanations for e.g. why "taking the limit" is a reasonable operation that can be completed).

Does anyone know some books that might introduce set theory, not necessarily from set theory itself, but rather for someone (most of us?) who have studied higher abstractions, before confronting set theory?

Comment: I like Paul Halmos' book Naive Set Theory. Maybe it is what you're looking for. It can be described (Wikipedia) as an "informal presentation of an axiomatic set theory."

Comment: @par Could be. A quote on Amazon: "This book is a very specialized but broadly useful introduction to set theory. It is aimed at ‘the beginning student of advanced mathematics’ … who wants to understand the set-theoretic underpinnings of the mathematics he already knows or will learn soon.".

Comment: Maybe *Set Theory for the Working Mathematician*.

Comment: Elementary set theory from munkres topology

Comment: It sounds like you want to "skip the boring oarts" and go right to the middle. There are no shortcuts.